# Грамотность, тонкости русского языка

Tags: стилистика

Подобно тому, как жителям дельт сибирских рек, объевшимся черной икрой, мечтается о баклажанной, – некоторым  иностранным туристам в Бразилии наскучили пляжи, рестораны и аквапарки: они хотят острых ощущениий. 
Программа "word" пишет, что "предложение не согласовано". Поправьте все, какие найдете, ошибки, включая стиль, и оцените сложность восприятия фразы.

Answer (score 2):

**Подобно тому как жители в дельтах сибирских рек пресытились черной икрой и "мечтают о баклажанной", некоторым иностранным туристам в Бразилии уже наскучили пляжи, рестораны и аквапарки: они хотят новых, необычных, волнующих ощущений.**

Замечания

Подобные тексты рекламного характера должны иметь более "легкий" стиль, без сложных грамматических конструкций.

Слово "острый" не совсем подходит к ситуации (по грамматике и семантике), лучше его заменить рядом синонимов.

Мечтать о "баклажанной икре" можно сейчас только в  переносном смысле.

Comment: Согласен с правками, кроме "жители в дельтах" - либо "жители дельт", либо "живущие в дельтах".

Comment: Живущие - канцелярский стиль,  жители дельт сибирских рек - плохо читается, два беспредложных Р.п., фонетика не очень удачная. А без "дельт"  никак не обойтись?  Совсем убрать или заменить синонимом?

Comment: Если без "дельт", получится "жители сибирских рек" - то есть те, кто живет в реках, как рыбы. Синоним - можно. Например?

Comment: Мне не очень ясно, почему дельты сибирских рек  Вы обозначили как регион с большим потреблением черной икры. В Сети приводятся, например, такие данные http://www.kp.ru/guide/gde-dobyvajut-chernuju-ikru.html. Там сибирские реки упоминаются скорее в негативном плане. Поэтому мой совет - обозначьте  регион как-то иначе, притом так,  чтобы  ситуация с черной икрой  (если Вы используете ее для сравнения) была понятна, наглядна и не вызывала вопросов у читателей.

Comment: Sibylla,  а почему у вас "мечтают о баклажанной" в кавычках?

Comment: Серж,  это же условное значение.  Кто сейчас мечтает о баклажанной икре (она вполне доступна), поэтому фраза соотносится с известным фильмом "Иван Васильевич меняет профессию".

Comment: Пусть негров (на сегодняшний день) в Европе больше, чем в Африке, самая холодная точка – на южном  полюсе, а икры полным-полно в Вологодской области. Но, не звучит это, нужно яркое сравнение. Вот новый вариант…
Жители дальневосточных приморских сел, коих воротит от красной икры – мечтают о баклажанной, а некоторым иностранным туристам в Бразилии наскучили пляжи, рестораны и аквапарки: они хотят новых, необычных, волнующих ощущений. Предприимчивые кариоки помогут этим людям избавиться от отягощающей кошелек валюты, организуя индивидуальные туры к фавелам в сопровождении штатного полицейского.

Answer (score 0):

Построение предложения нелогично: в форме пояснения ("подобно тому как...") приводится неочевидное и требующее осознания утверждение, к которому предлагается приравнять нечто вполне правдоподобное, реалистичное (некоторые туристы хотят экзотики). Сравнение того и другого, конечно, возможно, но при другой логике. Например, чтобы подчеркнуть новизну явления, можно противопоставить названному факту нечто гротескное: *туристы вместо роскоши вдруг захотели острых ощущений - это как объевшись чёрной икрой, возжелать баклажанной.*

Comment: Даю следующую по тексту фразу, чтобы стало понятно, о чем речь.Предприимчивые кариоки  организовали для таких людей экскурсии по фавелам, которые проводятся в сопровождении штатного полицейского.  Это и есть гротеск, причем на грани нелогичности, даже некоторого идиотизма: туристы хотят посмотреть "помойку" и платят за это деньги.

Comment: Я говорю о том, что формулировка "подобно тому" обычно вводит нечто очевидное и понятное для объяснения непонятного. В вашем же случае (из-за выбора вводного выражения и последовательности изложения) вышло, что понятное для собеседника и гротескное для вас (что вы пытаетесь до него донести) как бы объясняется собеседнику через фантастичное - это и выглядит нелогичным.

Comment: «туристы вместо роскоши вдруг захотели острых ощущений - это как объевшись чёрной икрой, возжелать баклажанной». Слишком сухо, не художественно. Выше привожу новый, обработанный вариант.

Comment: Это был не вариант, а упрощённый пример более логичного сочетания тех же утверждений.